# Connect multiple task lists into one master task list or view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, task-list, query

I have lots of project sites each with their own task list. I want to create a master task list (or view or whatever?) on the parent site that can display all tasks in all of these project task lists. ideally it can then be filtered too.
I know its possible but just wanted to find the easiest most effective way of doing this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a master task list is by using a custom display template. So, you can place a content search web part on the page you would like, and in the query of the CSWP, you can configure to return only items that are using the task content type (I usually create a custom content type that all my tasks list use - keep a note of its content type id).

Here is a good resource on how to [create a custom display template](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1/) (if you don't have experience creating one)

Answer (score 0):

Try using basic workflow to create new items in a master list each time an item is created in one of the separate ones.  I think it might be better to do it this way so you can put in meta data columns for each one of your separate list into the master.  You would make a workflow on each of the separate list to do this in SharePoint designer.  Pretty straight forward. Then you can make all of the views you want based off of the different list information in the master.

Comment: If a task item was then updated in the master list would this update the original project task list??

Comment: No, you would have to write another workflow on the master list to update those as well.  You could use lookup fields, but you would not be able to modify those on the master list.  I usually use a combination of workflow and JQuery (SPServices) to create multiple list connections like what you are trying to do.  I am doing it now for a project I am working on.

Comment: Should they not edit their items in the original list and not the master? The master is for viewing purposes only yes? If so, just make the master read only fields and that will solve the back and forth issue.